# R edgar package - issue with geBusinDescr

Tags: r, edgar

I want to retrieve the business description section of 74 companies using R edgar package and function getBusinDescr(). When I run my line of code, all the filings were downloaded via getFilings(). But then, the following error results: "Error in writeLines(product.descr2, filename2) : object 'product.descr2' not found". What caused this and how can I fix this issue?
Thanks in advance for your input.
PS-I apologize ahead of time for any mistakes in this question. This is my first question on stack overflow. I hope I have asked it according to the rules.

I have search online for how to fix this error, but could not find an answer. I did, however, find this webpage:  https://rdrr.io/cran/edgar/src/R/getBusinessDescr.R
which, to my knowledge, describes the code for this function in its entirety. Here, I found the probable location of the error: "writeLines(product.descr2, filename2)". However, I do not understand the code enough to know how to solve this issue.

```
    install.packages("edgar")
    install.packages("edgarWebR")
    library(edgar)
    library(edgarWebR)

    #retrieve BusinDesc (Item 1)
    filings.BusinDes.2018<-getBusinDescr(cik.no=CIK,filing.year=2018)

    #where CIK is a vector of CIK codes (as integers) for all 74 companies
    #for replicability here are some CIK codes:
    CIK.codes<-c(918160,1164727,831259,73309,1022671)

    #results/output in console
    Downloading fillings. Please wait...  100%
    Extracting 'Item 1' section... 0%                                                                                 
    Error in writeLines(product.descr2, filename2) : 
      object 'product.descr2' not found
```

I expected the output to show a data frame with basic filing information and a folder in the project titled "Business descriptions text" which includes the business descriptions for each company as text. However, in this case, the folder exists, but it is empty. In the console, the following error message shows:

```
    Error in writeLines(product.descr2, filename2) : 
      object 'product.descr2' not found
```

What is the source of this error and how can I fix it? 
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I don't think you gave the complete code that would produce that error.

Comment: I executed teh assignment of numbers to CIK.codes first and then I get no error with `filings.BusinDes.2018 <-getBusinDescr( cik.no=CIK.codes, filing.year=2018)`